# Enable spell Checker in Samsung Devices - Android

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-spellcheck

In my application i have One `EditText`. I test my application in `Google Nexus`, `Lenovo` and `Samsung` Devices. Other than Samsung Device When i type wrong word it shows with an `red underline`. But in Samsung device it is not working. I didn't do anything to enable it on those devices. But Samsung it is not working. And i saw option in Setting page to `enable/disable spell checker`. But in Samsung i didn't see that setting.

**How can i enable spell checker in Samsung Tablets?**

My samsung Android Version 4.1.1.

Note: I need enable spell checker programmatically.

Negative votes are welcome. Please put the comments here. Why adding negative votes.

My setting screen looks like [image: this]

My layout EditText Code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/DwEdit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:minLines="7"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences">
    <requestFocus /></EditText>
```

Comment: Did you succeed to solve it?  I was trying to reach you in the comments at the answer below

Comment: Nope. http://androidforums.com/threads/spell-checker-in-samsung-tablet.918263/

Answer (score 0):

Open android **setting menu** then **languages & input** 
then check spelling indicator [x].

[image]

I think android provides a Spell Check service by default. Assuming that you didn't look for it in the developer website, here goes the link,

**[developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html)**

Also it looks like the examples are available with the sdk package itself.

and check this **[tutorial](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/09/spell-checker-tutorial-in-android-with.html#.VVBfIJMnUWI)**

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add this. I need enable spell checker programmatically.

Comment: And my setting page very much different from this.

Comment: In Android 4.0+ sometimes get a red underline in Edittext property by default, to disable such suggestion put this attribute in edittext layout 
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Comment: in java you can use like that

mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

Comment: I tried.I know this will disable the suggestion. By default my other devices working. And if i add this attribute  even the text suggestion also gone.

Comment: try this one in edittext tag
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine"

Comment: Did you succeed to solve it? I also have this problem, but in an even worse situation. My only device is Samsung :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm a day late and dollar short, but many Samsung tablets, around the Android KitKat error, don't have a spell checker!  You will not find the setting in Settings because Samsung removed it!  But, given a properly written spell checker, it can be made to work.  I am completely useless when it comes to spelling and was extremely disappointed when I got my new Samsung Galaxy TabPRO SM-T900 12.2" (now with Android Lollipop (v5.1.1)) and it didn't have a spell checker.

Luckily (and I say luckily, because it is no longer available), I had already purchased QuickSpell from MobiSystems and, it works!  It was originally written as a default spell checker replacement, so it properly makes a spell checking service available.

Mobi is pretty good with customer service request, so if you still have this problem (or just want misspellings underlined in red again on any device), write Mobi.

In the meantime, if anyone knows of a good replacement for the default (QuickSpell is getting old), please share.  I am thinking of writing a newer replacement, but I currently have a working solution and a lot on my plate.

I write test apps and classes with AIDE on my tablet, so I use it daily.  If I can find something more modern with a 12" screen, I may upgrade, but so far, no joy.